# How to do simple mongoose findOne with multiple conditions?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, find, conditional-statements

How can I perform this findOne query with multiple conditions? Or a substitute method (preferrably an equally simple one) if it is not possible...

```
User.findOne({ 'email': email }, function (err, user) {

        if (err) {
            request.session.flash = {
                type: "danger",
                message: "Failed to log you in, error occurred."
            };
            response.redirect("/snippet/");
        }
```

I have tried

```
User.findOne({ 'email': email, 'pwd': pwd }, function (err, user) {
```

and

```
User.findOne({ 'email': email $and 'pwd': pwd }, function (err, user) {
```

and

```
User.findOne({ 'email': email}, $and: {'pwd': pwd}, function (err, user) {
```

Comment: The first one in the list of what you've tried is how you do it. What's not working about it?

Answer (score 7):

Try using the mongoose promise system (`.exec()`). The [query](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) inside `.findOne()` should be a single object.

```
User
    .findOne({email: email, pwd: pwd})
    .exec(function(err, user){
        ...
    });
```

Sidenote - it looks like this is for authenticating a a user login. It might be a better strategy to query just on the email, then try to match the passwords to give more depth to the error responses than a blanket 'Invalid login' type response.

```
User
    .findOne({email: email}) //If not found, no user with that email exists
    .exec(function(err, user){
        var hashed_pwd = hashPassword(pwd);
        if(!hashed_pwd === user.pwd){
            //If they don't match, user entered wrong password
        }
        ...
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
User.findOne({ 'email': email, 'pwd': pwd }, function (err, user) {
```

this syntax is correct. if this isn't returning any results, it means you didn't match any records.

my guess is that your `pwd` field is hashed / encrypted and that you need to run the same hash / encryption on your `pwd` variable before doing this `findOne`

Answer (score 0):

When the mongoDB is returning your docs, if it has not found `Data` then it will return `null` .
You can check your `docs` if it is null then response with some other page.
On the other hand if `docs` have data respond with the next page.

```
if(docs)
    respond("your content");
else
  respond("error page incorrect credentials")
```

I was doing the mistake thinking that it will create an exception `err`, but it's not an error it is simply a `null` data.